# (Java) Draw a line from point (x,y) to (x2,y2) in array of pixels?

Tags: java, line

I am trying to draw a line between to co-ordinates on an array of pixels. The following code almost works, it produces a line going to the right places, however it does not fill in all of the pixels, but creates more of a dotted line :

```
    double pixelsAcross = xFinish - xStart;
    double pixelsUp = yFinish - yStart;

    double acrossTemp = pixelsAcross;
    double HCF = pixelsUp;

    if (acrossTemp > 0) {
        while (acrossTemp > 0) {
            double temp = acrossTemp;
            acrossTemp = HCF % acrossTemp;
            HCF = temp;
        }

        pixelsUp /= HCF;
        pixelsAcross /= HCF;
    }

    double repeats = (xFinish - xStart) / (pixelsAcross);
    if (xFinish - xStart == 0 || xFinish + xStart == 0) {
        repeats = (yFinish - yStart) / (pixelsUp);
    }

    int count = 0;

    int xPos = xStart;
    int yPos = yStart;

    while (count <= repeats) {
        screen.pixels.setColor(RED, xPos, yPos);
        xPos += pixelsAcross;
        yPos += pixelsUp;
        count++;
    }
```

It works by calculating the gradient as a fraction, then uses the numerator to work out how many pixels to go up and the denominator for across per repeat (these are simplified to the lowest available form).

How can I make it fill in the pixels between the ones I am currently creating, to make it a full line instead of a dotted line? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: What kind of object is `screen`? Is there no method for drawing line in this object, or to get the `Graphics` object and then call `drawLine()` on it.

Comment: screen is a custom class, I don't want to use 'Graphics' as I have other UI elements that need to be drawn in front of it. I will try the line algorithm

Comment: The Bresenham's algorithm works, but I can't work out the best way to detect the octant from the gradient (I worked out how to calculate 0, 1, 6 and 7, but not the others)